# Creation of the tag : alternate-solution

Tags: support, tagging

I propose to create this tag : [alternate-solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-solution) for my most [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695605/evaluating-the-integral-int-frac-1-sqrt3-frac1-sqrt3-fracx4/3695611#3695611). This tag is to be used when the user is asking different approaches for the same question.

Is there such a tag existing already? If not, can I proceed to create this?

Comment: Why not use [tag:alternative-proof] ?

Comment: @Sil The question I linked is actually an answer I have reached for an integral. Would it still be okay to use an alternate **proof** tag?

Comment: In the question body you are asking for other way of proving the integral is equal to the given value, so it seems to satisfy the tag description: "If you already have a proof for some result but want to ask for a different proof (using different methods)."

Comment: @Sil alright ..

Answer (score 5):

I am against the creation of such a tag. It would be a "meta tag" and for the most part we try to avoid those.

The information that you are searching for an alternative solution should be conveyed in the body of the post.

Comment: Yes I have already done that. (It's the whole point of the question in fact) .